# is_enabled returns true each time in the loop for Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, isenabled

I have the code below which searches for an element. if the element is not found it click on the next page. What I want is, if the element is not found till the last page it should print "Element not found".

```
elpath=f"//span[contains(text(),[value})]"
while True:
    time sleep(2)
    try:
        driver.find element_by_xpath(elpath).click()
        break
    except Exception:
        if driver.find element_by_xpath("Xpath to click Next Page").is_enabled():
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("Xpath to click Next Page").click()
        else:
            print("Element Not Found")
            break
```

but when I checked `driver.find element_by_xpath("Xpath to click Next Page").is_enabled()` returns ***True*** even if the next button is disabled(i.e the last page of the list)

Please find below the HTML codes for the Next Button:

***For Disabled Button***

```
<button mat-icon-button="" type="button" class="mat-focus-indicator mat-tooltip-trigger mat-paginator-navigation-next mat-icon-button mat-button-base_mat-animation-noopable mat-button-disabled" aria-label="Next page" disabled="true">
<span class="mat-button-wrapper">
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" focusable="false" class="mat-paginator-icon"> <path d="M08 6G8.59 8.32 13.23 121-821 4L10 142-6b">
</Path>
</svg>
</span>
<span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple mat-button-ripple-round"> </span><span class="mat-button-focus-overlay">
</span>
</button>
```

***For Normal Button***

```
<button mat-icon-button="" type="button" class="mat-focus-indicator mat-tooltip-trigger mat-paginator-navigation-next mat-icon-button mat-button-base_mat-animation-noopable" aria-label="Next page"> 
<span class="mat-button-wrapper">
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" focusable="false" class="mat-paginator-icon"> <path d="M08 6G8.59 8.32 13.23 121-821 4L10 142-6b">
</Path>
</svg>
</span>
<span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple mat-button-ripple-round">
</span>
<span class="mat-button-focus-overlay">
</span>
</button>
```

Can anyone suggest an alternative method?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Can you share a link to the web page?

Comment: sorry, the web page is private, you wont be able to access it. Is there anything else i could do to help?

Comment: I think this can help you. Use a XPATH to match the next page only when is enable, you can use //button[xx...xx and not(@disabled)] . check true or false on get element

Comment: Check the exceptions and include it in your post.  (for clicking page button, and then clicking the Next button... try/catch that one)  It'll tell us something.  You may need to use webdriverwaits with expected conditions here.  (It would eliminate the need for the sleep)

Comment: also, when checking for that <span> I'd suggest using find_elements... you'll get back an empty array if it's not found.  You can then if/then based on whether the array size is 0.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is with indentation. Looks like `time sleep(2)` is not with the same indentation as the inner `try-except` block.
This causes that immediately after clicking the `next page` button the next page is not yet loaded so Selenium actually get's the previous page `next page` element.
Also, you have a typo, you are missing `_` it should be `find_element_by_xpath`.
Also, typo in `elpath=f"//span[contains(text(),[value})]"` while it should be `elpath=f"//span[contains(text(),{value})]"`
So, please try this:

```
elpath=f"//span[contains(text(),{value})]"
while True:
    time sleep(2)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(elpath).click()
        break
    except Exception:
        if driver.find_element_by_xpath("Xpath to click Next Page").is_enabled():
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("Xpath to click Next Page").click()
        else:
            print("Element Not Found")
            break
```

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake from my end. i have corrected that on the code above. That is not the issue.

Comment: Hmm, OK. 1)do you use implicit wait with your code? 2) Does this code actually goes thro all the pages and still tries to click the next button on the last page where it is disabled?

Comment: yes the rest of the code contains implicit wait in some parts. the above code works fine if the element id present and does the further steps. if the element is present it breaks from the loop.

Comment: That's strange. Looks like the issue is with something that you didn't share here.

Comment: Maybe you are using non unique locator so there is some other element matching this locator and that element is enabled?

Comment: i have shared everything the only difference between the element code is `disabled="true"` is present extra in the last page button. but when i check it using `driver.find element_by_xpath("Xpath to click Next Page").is_enabled()` it is giving me **True** even when its the last page so the code clicks on the next button  and thats a infinite loop.

Comment: I understand. need to actually see that, to debug the real code run there.

Comment: its protected website.. or else i would have given you the link. i really dont understand why the `driver.find element_by_xpath("Xpath to click Next Page").is_enabled()` is giving **True** even though its disabled in the last page.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code once.

```
try:
    driver.find element_by_xpath(elpath).click()
    break
except Exception:
    if driver.find element_by_xpath("Xpath to click Next Page").get_attribute('disabled') == None:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("Xpath").click()
    elif driver.find element_by_xpath("Xpath").get_attribute('disabled') == "true":
        print("Element Not Found")
        break
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i tried out this method. Its giving me the same result as before. it is not even getting in the **elif** part

Comment: Print the `driver.find element_by_xpath("Xpath").get_attribute('disabled')` in `if` block and see what it outputs.

Comment: yes.. its giving **None** . it traverses to the last page the keeps on clicking on the next button ..even though its disabled.

Comment: As per the HTML, the `class` attribute is extended with `mat-button-disabled`. Try to use this in the xpath. So if the class attribute contains `disabled` it should break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are running into a timing issue. I think the best way to avoid it is to make sure that the page has changed before attempting to click or checking for enabled. In Selenium terms, an element reference has gone "stale" when the page or part of the page changes either by navigating to a new page or through refreshing a portion of the page, etc. The way we can detect this is by using a `WebDriverWait` and wait for `staleness_of`.

I also broke out the locators to the top of the code block because it makes the code easier to read and the locators easier to manage if something changes.

See my updates to your code below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

ele_locator=(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),[value])]")
next_page_locator = (By.XPATH, "next page XPath")
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element(ele_locator).click()
        break
    except Exception:
        next_page = driver.find_element(next_page_locator)
        if next_page.is_enabled():
            next_page.click()
            wait.until(EC.staleness_of(ele))
        else:
            print("Element Not Found")
            break
```

NOTE: If you are using implicit waits, you will want to turn them off. Mixing implicit and explicit waits (`WebDriverWait`) is expressly warned against in the docs.

Comment: thank you. i got what you are trying to convey.. let me try this code.  im not able to get this line working : `wait.until(EC.staleness_of(ele))` what is EC? and ele?

Comment: Updated my answer with imports. EC is the standard for ExpectedConditions, see [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits).